# Multipart File upload in MERN Stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, multipartform-data

I am trying to Implement File upload feature using multipart to speed up upload for big file size.

I am unable to figure out why this is not working.

I am providing environment variables via console for now.

When I click send button, nothing happens. Both my servers are running fine (I am quite sure of them)

Issue:

1> when I do

```
axios.post(`http://localhost:4000`, data)
```

it throws an error. How shall I post my file (data) to backend?

Please point out the mistakes or things to be done.

Thanks in Advance!

**Following is my FileUpload.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class FileUpload extends Component {

  constructor (props) {

   super(props);

    this.submitFile = this.submitFile.bind(this);

    this.fileInput = React.createRef();
  }


  submitFile = (event) => {

    event.preventDefault();
    var data = {

      file: this.fileInput.current.files[0],
      name: this.fileInput.current.files[0].name
    };

    axios.post(`http://localhost:4000`, data)

    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })

    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (

      <form onSubmit={this.submitFile}>
        <input type='file' ref={this.fileInput} />

        <button type='submit'>Send</button>
      </form>

    );
  }

}

 export default FileUpload;
```

**My backend Node upload.js looks like following:**

```
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var cred = require('../aws/config')

const AWS_SECRET_ACCESS = cred.access();
const AWS_ACCESS_KEY = cred.awskey();


// configure the keys for accessing AWS
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: ''
});

// create S3 instance
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3:s3,
    bucket: '',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
  cb(null, {fileName: 'uploadit'});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString())
    }
  })
})


module.exports = upload;
```

Comment: front code looks good.I don't know multiparty module. Did you try https://github.com/expressjs/multer ? Never had any issue with it.

Comment: ok. I will give it a try. Please upvote the question otherwise it will be accounted in bad ones.

Comment: I did d same using express-fileupload npm package. It is easy to implement. You can give it a try. https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload

Comment: can't move like this. there might be more packages. Please point out the mistakes in above code if possible

Comment: You should use https://github.com/TTLabs/EvaporateJS for uploading multipart directly from browser (if web app). You should not write any kind of backend for upload on aws because there will be 2 Round Trip Times when you'll upload a file and if file is big, connection will lose

Answer (score 0):

I always upload my photos on cloudinary.
You can save them locally too but on the long term I don't think this is a solution.

**Backend**

```
import express from 'express'; 
import webpackMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackConfig from './webpack.config.js';
const app = express();
app.use(webpackMiddleware(webpack(webpackConfig)));
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary');

cloudinary.config({ 
  cloud_name: 'your cloud name', 
  api_key: 'your api key', 
  api_secret: 'your api secret' 
});

app.use(multipartMiddleware);
app.post('/images', multipartMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  // file upload
  let formData = Object.values(req.files);
  let photoName = Object.keys(req.files);

  cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    formData[0].path,
    function () { res.json('Uploaded!')},
    {
      public_id: photoName[0],
      crop: 'scale',
      width: 1200,
      height: 400,
      quality: 100,
      tags: ['usedCars', 'usedCars']
    }
  )
});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Your app on port:', port);
});
```

**Frontend**

```
  // input type file
  <input type="file"
   accept="image/*"
   onChange={evt => this.updateFileValue(evt)}
   id="carPhoto"/>

  // updating state
  updateFileValue(evt) {
    this.setState({
       carPhoto: evt.target.files[0]
    });
  }

  // post request
  Apis.addCarsList(this.state).then((res) => {
    const fd = new FormData();
    const photoName = "a name for your photo, I usually get  the mongoId as a photo name";
    fd.append(res.data, this.state.carPhoto, photoName);
    axios.post('/images', fd).then((res) => {
      // do w/e
    });
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution but I don't use cloudinary. Please point out the mistakes in above code if possible

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're doing almost everything correct, except for one small detail that caught my attention.

1. your `fileName` is defined from `files.name`, which is `undefined` (try to console.log that to verify). What you need to do is give it a unique name, like for example a timestamp.

```js
app.post('/upload', (request, response) => {
  const form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(request, async (error, fields, files) => {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      try {
        const path = files.file[0].path;
        const buffer = fs.readFileSync(path);
        const type = fileType(buffer);
        const fileName = Date.now().toString();
        const data = await uploadFile(buffer, fileName, type);
        return response.status(200).send(data);
      } 

      catch (error) {
        return response.status(400).send(error);
      }
    });
});
```

Also make sure you're proxying your requests: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

Some additional debugging tricks, if you haven't tried that yet:

- Try to create a simple `get` route in your server just to make sure that client and server are talking to each other.
- Try to create first a `get` request to list your buckets to make sure that the communication with S3 works as expected: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listBuckets-property

I hope this helps!
Cheers!

Comment: Do have a look again. I noticed myself few things earlier but thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @VivekGupta comment here what went wrong so other people can also understand.

Comment: When I do post on localhost of the backend it does not reflect the post data. I have added the details in question

Comment: @VivekGupta can you specify the error, it could be lots of things! Also if you could share the code of your post route in the backend, would be nice.